# How to find where a method is defined at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime, methods, definition

We recently had a problem where, after a series of commits had occurred, a backend process failed to run. Now, we were good little boys and girls and ran `rake test` after every check-in but, due to some oddities in Rails' library loading, it only occurred when we ran it directly from Mongrel in production mode.

I tracked the bug down and it was due to a new Rails gem overwriting a method in the String class in a way that broke one narrow use in the runtime Rails code.

Anyway, long story short, is there a way, at runtime, to ask Ruby where a method has been defined? Something like `whereami( :foo )` that returns `/path/to/some/file.rb line #45`? In this case, telling me that it was defined in class String would be unhelpful, because it was overloaded by some library.

I cannot guarantee the source lives in my project, so grepping for `'def foo'` won't necessarily give me what I need, not to mention if I have *many* `def foo`'s, sometimes I don't know until runtime which one I may be using.

Comment: In Ruby 1.8.7, a special method was added specifically to find this information (and it's still there in 1.9.3)... details in my answer below.

Comment: Long time years ago I wrote an article that answers these questions https://blog.widefix.com/find-method-source-location/

Answer (score 457, accepted):

This is really late, but here's how you can find where a method is defined:

http://gist.github.com/76951

```
# How to find out where a method comes from.
# Learned this from Dave Thomas while teaching Advanced Ruby Studio
# Makes the case for separating method definitions into
# modules, especially when enhancing built-in classes.
module Perpetrator
  def crime
  end
end

class Fixnum
  include Perpetrator
end

p 2.method(:crime) # The "2" here is an instance of Fixnum.
#<Method: Fixnum(Perpetrator)#crime>
```

If you're on Ruby 1.9+, you can use [`source_location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location)

```
require 'csv'

p CSV.new('string').method(:flock)
# => #<Method: CSV#flock>

CSV.new('string').method(:flock).source_location
# => ["/path/to/ruby/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb", 180]
```

Note that this won't work on everything, like native compiled code. The [Method class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html) has some neat functions, too, like [Method#owner](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-owner) which returns the file where the method is defined.

EDIT: Also see the `__file__` and `__line__` and notes for REE in the other answer, they're handy too. -- wg

Comment: source_location appears to work for 1.8.7-p334 using activesupport-2.3.14

Comment: after finding the method, try Method's `owner` method

Comment: What is the number two in `2.method(:crime)` ?

Comment: an instance of the class `Fixnum`

Comment: Important note:  This will not pull up any dynamically defined methods from `method_missing`.  So if you have a module or ancestor class with a `class_eval` or `define_method` inside of `method_missing`, then this method won't work.

Comment: What if there's no class or instance? e.g. `def something() create :stuff end`, how can I find out where `create` is being defined?

Comment: But really why is there a 2 there?

Comment: In reply to devius's comment, try self(:create).source_location or even method(:create).self_location

Comment: You can use `allocate` instead of `new`: `CSV.allocate.method(:flock).source_location`

Answer (score 87):

You can actually go a bit further than the solution above.  For Ruby 1.8 Enterprise Edition, there is the `__file__` and `__line__` methods on `Method` instances:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'activesupport'

m = 2.days.method(:ago)
# => #<Method: Fixnum(ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Numeric::Time)#ago>

m.__file__
# => "/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb"
m.__line__
# => 64
```

For Ruby 1.9 and beyond, there is `source_location` (thanks Jonathan!):

```
require 'active_support/all'
m = 2.days.method(:ago)
# => #<Method: Fixnum(Numeric)#ago>    # comes from the Numeric module

m.source_location   # show file and line
# => ["/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/.../numeric/time.rb", 63]
```

Comment: I get "NoMethodError: undefined method" for both `__file__` and `__line__` on any `Method` class instance, ex: `method(:method).__file__`.

Comment: Which version of ruby do you have?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: On Ruby 1.9, `m.__file__` and `m.__line__` have been replaced with `m.source_location`.

Comment: `source_location` works with Ruby 1.9 and upwards, including 2.1

Answer (score 39):

I'm coming late to this thread, and am surprised that nobody mentioned `Method#owner`.

```
class A; def hello; puts "hello"; end end
class B < A; end
b = B.new
b.method(:hello).owner
=> A
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you're the first to reference the [Method class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html) explicitly. Another lesser known treasure introduced in 1.9: `Method#parameters`.

Answer (score 15):

Copying my answer from a newer [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012109/get-class-location-from-class-object) that adds new information to this problem.

Ruby **1.9** has method called [source_location](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location):

> Returns the Ruby source filename and line number containing this method or nil if this method was not defined in Ruby (i.e. native)

This has been backported to **1.8.7** by this gem:

- [ruby18_source_location](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/ruby18_source_location)

So you can request for the method:

```
m = Foo::Bar.method(:create)
```

And then ask for the `source_location` of that method:

```
m.source_location
```

This will return an array with filename and line number.
E.g for `ActiveRecord::Base#validates` this returns:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.method(:validates).source_location
# => ["/Users/laas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@arveaurik/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb", 81]
```

For classes and modules, Ruby does not offer built in support, but there is an excellent Gist out there that builds upon `source_location` to return file for a given method or first file for a class if no method was specified:

- [ruby where_is module](https://gist.github.com/1236979)

In action:

```
where_is(ActiveRecord::Base, :validates)

# => ["/Users/laas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@arveaurik/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb", 81]
```

On Macs with TextMate installed, this also pops up the editor at the specified location.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the `#source_location` can help to find where is the method come from.

ex:

```
ModelName.method(:has_one).source_location
```

Return

```
[project_path/vendor/ruby/version_number/gems/activerecord-number/lib/active_record/associations.rb", line_number_of_where_method_is]
```

OR

```
ModelName.new.method(:valid?).source_location
```

Return

```
[project_path/vendor/ruby/version_number/gems/activerecord-number/lib/active_record/validations.rb", line_number_of_where_method_is]
```

Answer (score 7):

This may help but you would have to code it yourself.  Pasted from the blog:

> Ruby provides a method_added()
>   callback that is invoked every time a
>   method is added or redefined within a
>   class. It’s part of the Module class,
>   and every Class is a Module. There are
>   also two related callbacks called
>   method_removed() and
>   method_undefined().

http://scie.nti.st/2008/9/17/making-methods-immutable-in-ruby

Answer (score 7):

If you can crash the method, you'll get a backtrace which will tell you exactly where it is.

Unfortunately, if you can't crash it then you can't find out where it has been defined.  If you attempt to monkey with the method by overwriting it or overriding it, then any crash will come from your overwritten or overridden method, and it won't be any use.

Useful ways of crashing methods:

1. Pass `nil` where it forbids it - a lot of the time the method will raise an `ArgumentError` or the ever-present `NoMethodError` on a nil class.
2. If you have inside knowledge of the method, and you know that the method in turn calls some other method, then you can overrwrite the other method, and raise inside that.

Comment: If you have access to the code, you can just as easily insert `require 'ruby-debug'; debugger`  in your code where you want to drop in.

Comment: "Unfortunately, if you can't crash it then you can't find out where it has been defined." Is not true. Se other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Very late answer :) But earlier answers did not help me

```
set_trace_func proc{ |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
}
# call your method
set_trace_func nil
```

Comment: Why are you passing `nil` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit from documentation: «Establishes proc as the handler for tracing, or disables tracing if the parameter is `nil`.»

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do something like this:

foo_finder.rb:

```
 class String
   def String.method_added(name)
     if (name==:foo)
        puts "defining #{name} in:\n\t"
        puts caller.join("\n\t")
     end
   end
 end
```

Then ensure foo_finder is loaded first with something like

```
ruby -r foo_finder.rb railsapp
```

(I've only messed with rails, so I don't know exactly, but I imagine there's a way to start it sort of like this.)

This will show you all the re-definitions of String#foo. With a little meta-programming, you could generalize it for whatever function you want.   But it does need to be loaded BEFORE the file that actually does the re-definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can always get a backtrace of where you are by using `caller()`.

Comment: This is useful to find what called you, but not good when you're trying to find where something was defined.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do this in the context of a rails app, you can use the pry gem in the same scope of the method call (in this case, the method was `render` used in the rails view, so i placed this in the view just before it):

```
<% binding.pry %>
```

Then in the debugger I ran this, which showed the exact location of the method that was called:

```
method(:render).source_location                       
=> ["/Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb",
 30]
```

(the important part is the end, showing the namespace the method came from)

```
gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb
```

From there you can isolate which part of the documentation should be looked at:

[image]