# How do you detect that monkey patching has occurred in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How do you check that monkey patching has been done to a specific class in Ruby?  If that is possible, is it also possible to get the previous implementation(s) of the attribute that's been patched?

Comment: Might be related to my ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-ruby-method-is-defined-at-runtime - if someone figures this out, pls let me know too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this blog posting that touches on how to use method_added to track monkey patching.  It's not too hard to extend it to track the methods that were patched.

http://hedonismbot.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/monkey-business-2/:

> By using open classes, we can re-define method_added for instances of Class and do some custom stuff every time a method is defined for any class.  In this example, we’re re-defining method_added so that it tracks where the method was last defined.
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                                                                                                           
>
> class Class
>     @@method_history = {}
>
>     def self.method_history
>         return @@method_history
>     end
>
>    def method_added(method_name)
>        puts "#{method_name} added to #{self}"
>        @@method_history[self] ||= {}
>        @@method_history[self][method_name] = caller
>    end
>
>    def method_defined_in(method_name)
>        return @@method_history[self][method_name]
>    end
> end
> ```

Answer (score 8):

There are the hooks `method_added` and `method_undefined`. Garry Dolley has written an I[mmutable module](http://scie.nti.st/2008/9/17/making-methods-immutable-in-ruby) that prevents monkey patching.