# Can I find the file/linenumber where a method was defined?

Tags: ruby, reflection

## Duplicate: [How To Find Where A Ruby Method Is Defined At Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-ruby-method-is-defined-at-runtime)

---

With a given object, is it possible to find out where each method was defined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-ruby-method-is-defined-at-runtime

Comment: huh why is nobody closing it?

Comment: I don't have the power, as it were.  Vote me up, in 100 more points I will (grin).

Comment: I swear I searched before posting the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the fact, it will be pretty tough, but you can use a hook method to observe the line numbers where a method is defined.

```
class X < Object

  def X.method_added(symbol)
    puts "adding method #{symbol} to class X from #{caller(0)}"
  end

end


class X
  def a_method
  end
end
```