# In Ruby on Rails, when in the View, can you dump out the files and line numbers before reaching View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

The first layer is routing and the second layer the controller, so when in View, is there a way to dump out the path or filenames and line numbers of route and controller before reaching view?

I wanted to do this because `www.example.com/stories/12345` is showing a page, but stories_controller.rb doesn't have a `def index` or `def show`

**Update:** I guess it might be as if the program has an error, in which case it will show an application trace and a rails trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually there is no other alternative than using a `index` or `show` and it has to be defined inside the class StoriesController. But it does not mean that those methods are defined inside the file "stories_controller.rb".

There are a few options:

- they are defined in the ApplicationController from which it derives. Or there is another parent-class.
- for instance, when you use [ActiveScaffold](http://activescaffold.com/) your controller contains a single line `active_scaffold` that adds all the standard CRUD actions (index, show, ...)

To see where a method is defined, you could type inside your `script/console` session

```
StoriesController.new.method('index')
```

and it would return a set of classes/modules, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-ruby-method-is-defined-at-runtime).

For instance, in our ApplicationController we include a module that defines a method `login_required`, and that looks like this:

```
>> ApplicationController.new.method(:login_required)
=> #<Method: ApplicationController(PilgrimBase::Base::Authenticated)#login_required>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: StoriesController.method('index') errors out... this one shows something but doesn't say where:
>> StoriesController.instance_method('index')
=> #<UnboundMethod: StoriesController#index>

Comment: I am sorry, you have to write `StoriesController.new.method('index')`. I corrected my answer accordingly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesnt really answer your question, but ...
you can see your routes by doing

```
rake routes
```

do you have show.html.erb in your app/views/stories/ ?