# Is it possible to find in which file/line a method was defined in Ruby (MRI)?

Tags: ruby

Ruby definitely stores such information at runtime, as it is printed in stack traces - but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way of accessing it. Is there a solution? (other than grepping the sources, or passing nonsense arguments to method in hope of getting the stack trace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9, you have Method#source_location:

```
require 'yaml'    
p YAML.method(:load).source_location => ["C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb", 132]
```

It appears there's a request to backport source_location to 1.8 (http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2180), but I'm not sure if/when that will happen.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could find: [How to find where a method is defined at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-ruby-method-is-defined-at-runtime)