# How can I programmatically determine which class/module defines a method being called?

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming, dispatch

In Ruby, how can I programmatically determine which class/module defines a method being called?

Say in a given scope I invoke `some_method()`.  In the same scope I'd like to invoke a function `find_method(:some_method)` that would return which Class, Singleton Class or Module defines `some_method`.

Here's some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
class Foo
  include ...

  def bar
    ...
    some_method() # calls a method in scope, assume it exists

    find_method(:some_method) # Returns where the method is defined
                              # e.g. => SomeClassOrModule
    ...
  end
end
```

I'm guessing I have to use a complex mixture of reflective functions, starting with `self` and using `self.ancestors` to walk up the inheritance tree, using `method_defined?` to check if a method is defined on a Class or Module, and probably some other tricks to inspect scopes from the innermost to the outermost (since the code may run within, e.g., an `instance_eval`).

I just don't know the correct order and all the subtleties of the Ruby metamodel to implement `find_method` such that it's both exhaustive in its search and correct from a method dispatch resolution perspective.

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found that this was surprisingly simple. Neat!

Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/ddg#660129), to show how to actually return the owner class:

```
foo.method(:some_method).owner
```

Wrap that in an instance method if you find it necessary, but that's not really that bad, eh?

Comment: Sweet!  Yes, much easier than I expected :)