# method_missing visibility in Ruby

Tags: ruby, visibility, method-missing

`method_missing` shows up in `Object.private_methods`, not in `Object.public_methods`.

However, when I call `Object.method_missing :stupidmethod`, I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `stupidmethod' for Object:Class
```

I would expect to get

```
NoMethodError: private method `method_missing' called for Object:Class
```

because that's what I get when I try to invoke `Object`'s *other* private methods, e.g. `Object.chop`.

As more evidence, if I call `Object.method_missing` without an argument, I get

```
ArgumentError: no id given
```

So it seems like I *really am* invoking that "private" `method_missing` function from outside of its object.  Can you explain this?

---

EDIT: Thank you to Eugene in the comments.  `ruby --version` tells me 1.8.7.  Also, `irb --version` is 0.9.5(05/04/13).  Good to know that this behaves as I'd expect in the later versions.

Comment: maybe this [post](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/) has the answer

Comment: With MRI 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 I actually do get a `NoMethodError`. Which Ruby implementation are you using? What is the context of your code?

Comment: fwiw: I've verified that 1.9.3, 2.0, and rubinius all return a `private method method_missing` error.  1.8 and jruby (in 1.9 mode) return `undefined method stupidmethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the private method of `Object` that is called but the module method in `Kernel`. You can check which method is called with `set_trace_func` as described in the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453985/30344):

```
irb(main):001:1> set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|   printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname if id.to_s == 'method_missing' }
=> #<Proc:0x0423d278@(irb):1>
irb(main):002:0> Object.method_missing :test
c-call (irb):4  method_missing   Kernel
c-return (irb):4  method_missing   Kernel
NoMethodError: undefined method `test' for Object:Class
    from (irb):4
    from :0
```

As some commenters pointed out in MRIs newer than 1.8.7 this behaviour has changed: `method_missing` has been removed from `Kernel` and the private instance method from `Object` was moved to `BasicObject` which is the new superclass.