# See where a symbol is defined in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

I work on a pretty large rails project at work. Sometimes I need to hunt down class / constant definitions. Is there some built-in method in Ruby to do this for me? Example:

```
irb> SOME_CONSTANT.__file__
=> /some/path/to/a/file
```

Comment: Have you tried just grepping for "SOME_CONSTANT =" in your directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but methods *do* have a .source_location method on them. You can use this to find out where a class is actually implemented. (Since ruby lets you reopen classes, this could be in multiple places)

for example, given an instance of an object, *i*:

```
i.methods.map do |method_name| 
  method_obj = i.method(method_name)
  file, line = method_obj.source_location
  file #map down to the file name
end.uniq
```

will give you a list of all the files where *i*'s methods are implemented.

This will work for classes that have at least 1 method implemented in ruby. It won't work for constants, though.

Answer (score 1):

At the very beginning before any file is loaded, insert a line that defines the class/constant that you want to check as something other than a module. For example, suppose you have class or other kind of constant `A` within your code, and want to know where it is defined. Then, at the very beginning of the main file, write

```
A = nil
```

Then, when the program is run, whenever it first meets the definition of class/constant `A`, it will show something like

```
some_path_to_a_file:line_number in `some_method': A is not a class (TypeError)
```

or

```
some_path_to_a_file:line_number: warning: already initialized constant A
```

Then, `some_path_to_a_file:line_number` will be the location where `A` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby 1.9.2, @YenTheFirst's answer is correct: call `#source_location` on a Method object.

If you're using Ruby 1.8.7, then `#source_location` doesn't exist (yet). You'll need something like [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/1236979) of a method. (There's another one or two floating around, but I can't find the other one real quick).

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13015691/260122 there is (now) a gem [ruby18_source_location](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/ruby18_source_location) that backports `Method#source_location`.