# Find directory of subclass before initialization to configure dry-view paths

Tags: ruby, dry-rb

I'm using [dry-views](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-view/) in multiple Rails engines and I have to duplicate the configuration in every subclass.

```
class BaseView < Dry::View::Controller
  configure do |c|
    c.paths = [File.join(__dir__, 'templates')]
  end
end

class SubView < BaseView
  configure do |c|
    c.paths = [File.join(__dir__, 'templates')] # todo: remove me
  end
end
```

The reason is, that my views can be deeply nested in a sub folder of `app` ie.:

```
app/
app/foo/index.rb
app/foo/templates/index.html.erb
app/foo/bar/show.rb
app/foo/bar/templates/show.html.erb
```

Additionally the `BaseView` class does not live in the same gem in most of the cases.

If I delete the `configure` block from the `SubView` class, the template is not found anymore. The `__dir__` variable contains the directory path of the `BaseView` class.

I've tried to implement a after initialization method in the base class that has access to the directory of the subclass. But at that point the configuration is not possible anymore due to restrictions in `dry-rb` configuration. The configuration must happen before initialization.

The only solution I could come up with is to duplicate the `configure` block in each class, or have a gem/engine specific parent class that configures all possible template paths.

The usual approach of looking for the directory of a certain method that is implemented in each subclass does also not work in this case, since most views don't even define methods.

Is there better ways to access the directory of a given class during the load phase of this class in a method of the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseView < Dry::View::Controller
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.class_eval do
      configure do |c|
        c.paths = [File.join(__dir__, 'templates')]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Callback [`Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-inherited).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I had to add a `super` call in the first line of the `self.inherited` method since dry-configuration uses the same method. But then still the issue remains that `__dir__` always points to the directory of the base class. Have any ideas? I tried a few things from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012109/get-class-location-from-class-object but they don't work since the views don't declare methods on their own.

Comment: Try to use dynamic current directory lookup instead of `__dir__`, like [`Dir#getwd`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-getwd). Also, you might want to dynamically declare `self.inherited` on children for nested inheritance.