# How to find a method in rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking at some open source code to better familiarize myself with rails code.

I see the following in the `application_controller`

```
  def can_signup?
    [ :allowed, :needs_approval ].include? Setting.user_signup
  end
```

I can't seem to find where this method is defined in the code `Setting.user_signup`

`Setting` is a model

What can I be missing? link to code: https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L155-157

Grep output:

```
/rails_projects/fat_free_crm $ grep -r --include="*.rb" "user_signup" .
./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:    [ :allowed, :needs_approval ].include? Setting.user_signup
./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:      if Setting.user_signup == :needs_approval
./app/models/users/user.rb:    self.suspended? && self.login_count == 0 && Setting.user_signup == :needs_approval
./app/models/users/user.rb:    self.suspended_at = Time.now if Setting.user_signup == :needs_approval && !self.admin
./spec/controllers/authentications_controller_spec.rb:          Setting.stub!(:user_signup).and_return(:needs_approval)
./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:        Setting.stub!(:user_signup).and_return(:needs_approval)
./spec/models/users/user_spec.rb:    Setting.stub(:user_signup).and_return(:needs_approval)
./spec/models/users/user_spec.rb:    Setting.stub(:user_signup).and_return(:needs_approval)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the `Setting` model is using `method_missing`, which is a special method called (if defined) when a `NoMethodError` exception is raised.

More info on `method_missing` here:
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_method_missing.html

If you take a look to `method_missing` implementation in `Setting`:
https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm/blob/master/app/models/setting.rb#L54-65

You'll find that `Setting.user_signup` will become `Setting['user_signup']`, so the `[]` method will be called with `user_signup` as first argument:
https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm/blob/master/app/models/setting.rb#L69-84

That method (`[]`), according to documentation, will search a setting within a database table or a .yml file with the name equal to the first argument, and then returns the relative value.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby is a dynamic language the best way to look for a method is to search for the string itself. Keep in mind that since methods may be created dynamically there may not be an actual `def user_signup` anywhere in the code, still the method might exist.

To search for the string across all project you can use your editor(whichever that is - all of them has this option), or just use `grep -r user_signup .` from your app root.

Comment: I had done the grep but didn't find anything that would look like method initialization...I've updated the question