# Self Keyword in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a definition of a function in Ruby like this:

```
def is_fdi?
 self.get_fed_state =~ /fdi/i ? true : false
end
```

Here `is_fdi?` is a function returning a Boolean. As far as I understand `self.get_fed_state`  is a function call and its returned value is being compared with `/fd1/i`, but `get_fed_state` is not defined in the file anywhere.

Does anyone have any idea how `is_fdi?` is calling `get_fed_state`? Or, is there something that I should know to crack this?

Comment: `get_fed_state` likely **is** defined somewhere, if this code works. Is it an activerecord model? Also, that ternary operator is redundant. You can just use this: http://pastie.org/5487838 with the same effect

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have checked everywhere and this get_fed_state is not defined anywhre. what is activerecord model?

Comment: Where did you get that code from?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I got it from my team itself, and it is a working code. I have been a given task of understanding a ruby project Do you think this would have something to do with self?

Comment: i'm with sergio. can you confirm its not defined by doing `puts self.methods` and checking if its there?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I even did grep -r ' get_fed_state' . , but did not get any definitions, dont know what else I can do. thanks anyway

Comment: Do what I said and try some of the stuff from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime

Comment: may be your team makes use of #method_missing - http://www.trottercashion.com/2011/02/08/rubys-define_method-method_missing-and-instance_eval.html - which would at least explain why you cant find that method anywhere in your project

Comment: `self` is a reference to the instance the methods gets called on

Comment: Maybe `fed_state` is defined, and some other mechanism is defining a getter for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method. If you get a `NoMethodError: undefined method` it actually isn't defined. If it runs, then it is defined. It could be that it is defined in an external package the project uses, and not in the actual codebase.

Also you can shorten it like this:

```
def is_fdi?
 !!get_fed_state[/fdi/i]
end
```