# Why does this object respond_to :each but object.method(:each) raises an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've inherited a project in which an ActiveRecord model is giving me strange behaviour. This is the only model that's behaving this way, so far.

```
car = Car.first
car.respond_to?(:each) # true
```

There is no `each` method defined in `Car` that I can find.

I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime) that you can find out who injected the method, so I gave it a shot:

```
car.method(:each) # raises "undefined method `each' for class `Car'
```

I want to use `Car` with [draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper) but because my instance behaves like an Enumerable, draper treats it as such. Draper is not the issue, however.

What should I do to figure it out?

Comment: Post your `Car` model code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post without editing most of it (which probably defeats the purpose) because I'm not allowed to. Is there another way we can find out? It's quite a large model, anyway, at 1,286 lines.

Comment: Well, `respond_to?` can be overridden, and often is in order to get classes to behave consistently in the face of `method_missing`, but that's only a possible mechanism, not an explanation.  Without code, there's not much we can do.

Comment: If the file is too large, do a binary search on it. Delete almost all of it. Did that fix it? Undo, split the deleted part into two halves, delete one of them. If that helped, undo and delete the other. Otherwise, keep the half deleted. Split what's left into two halves, and so on.

Comment: Ok thanks folks will get back to you.

Comment: I agree, we need to see your Car model. What does **Car.respond_to?(:each)** return?

Comment: Your comments helped me find it! I used Dmitry's binary-search to figure out what caused it, and found the problem in a gem that the model is using. The gem, Mark Reed, overrides respond_to.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. Please don't only leave your answer in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments to my question helped me find it! I used Dmitry's binary-search to figure out what caused it, and found the problem in a gem that the model is using. The gem, Mark Reed, overrides `respond_to`. So the lesson is: if `responds_to` is funky, perhaps it's being overridden somewhere.