# Ruby. Which class a method is defined in?

Tags: methods, where-clause, defined

Do u guys know if it is possible to learn what class the method is defined in?

For example,

to_a is probably defined in Enumerable and in Numeric or elsewhere. Is there a function, like with class objects:

```
=> aaa=[1,2,3,4,5]
=> aaa.class
=> Array
```

Is there a method like "defined_in?" to learn which class a method is defined in?

```
=> to_a.defined_in?
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ruby 1.9 and up, you can use `Method#source_location`. On Ruby 1.8, there is a gem [ruby18_source_location](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/ruby18_source_location) that backports this functionality.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13015691/260122 and the other answers to the same question for a good discussion of further ways to analyze source code, including the debugger.

---

Edit: Sorry, I misread your question. To find out what class or module defined a method, use `Method#owner`. As in:

```
> %w(a a a).method(:to_a).owner
=> Array
```