# ActiveRecord#where returning instance when running specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm writing specs for some software and getting a weird behavior:  In the method I'm testing, I'm calling:

```
MyModel.where(special_identifier: opts[:ident]).first || MyModelBuilder.new(m).build
```

(note I don't want first_or_create or first_or_new since I'm using explicit builders here).  When I query `MyModel.where(...)` I should be getting back an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which is how it behaves in prod, dev, console, etc.  However, when running the specs, `where` returns a `MyModel` object.  Is this a bug, am I missing something?

Comment: it seems like you're stubbing the `where` method somewhere. Can you reproduce in a new rails app and post a link?

Comment: Haven't been able to reproduce with any other models.  However, I'm not stubbing anywhere in my tests yet.

Comment: Can you verify this behavior using `puts MyModel.where(...).inspect` in your test?

Comment: `MyModel.where(special_identifier: opts[:ident])` will give you an AR::Relation object, but calling first on it will get the instance out of it.

Comment: If `MyModelBuilder.new(m).build` is not important to the question, please take it out along with the "(note I don't want first_or_create or first_or_new since I'm using explicit builders here)". It raises more questions than it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DVG said in the comments, `MyModel.where(...)` returns a relation, but calling `.first` or `.last` on it should return an instance, not a relation. Similarly, if the where returns more than one record, then `.limit(...)`, `.to_a`, or `.all` on the relation would return the set of records.

If you are doing `MyModel.where(...)` and it is definitely not returning a relation, then you need to figure out where that is happening:

```
if !MyModel.where('').is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation
  raise "where was defined in #{MyModel.method(:where).source_location}"
end
```

That raise could be a `fail` instead, if in a spec.

If that doesn't work, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/660129/178651) for more ways to get the source of the method.

Now if `.first` returns nil, then your code:

```
MyModel.where(special_identifier: opts[:ident]).first || MyModelBuilder.new(m).build
```

is going to return whatever `MyModelBuilder.new(m).build` returns (or it might raise something).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have state in your database. Be wary of `before(:all)` blocks which can cause this. Also maybe consider something like the [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem.