# How to trace the singleton class and m_tbl in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I started to touch the meta-programming in Ruby

If I want to trace all the details in  meta-programming

Like to lookup `m_tbl` methods_table in a specific object,

I mean if there is a `test` method and defined in class `B`
`A < B`
`B < C`

What's the convenient way to know the method is defined in `class B`

Any good methods or tools to share about discovery the meta-programing in Ruby.

To look up all the relation between object's hierachy relation in quick way.

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find where a method is defined at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `method` method:

```
class C
  def c
  end
end

class B < C
  def b
  end
end

class A < B
  def a
  end
end

a = A.new

a.method(:b).owner
# => B
```