# Where is the method 'is_admin?' defined in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that calls

```
current_user.is_admin?
```

The code works fine, but I can't figure out where the `is_admin?` method is defined. I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), and [role_model](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model), but the method isn't in any of these projects' source code, or in mine...

I also tried finding the [owner of the method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356057/165673) by doing this in the Rails console:

```
current_user.method(:is_admin?).owner
=> #<Module:0x00000105253c98>
```

But that's not much help...

Comment: Try typing `current_user.method(:is_admin?).source_location`

Comment: @BroiSatse - Thanks! That did it... ill make an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I got the source location by doing:

```
current_user.method(:is_admin?).source_location
```

(Thanks to @BroiSatse for that)

That pointed me to this file in role_model:
https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model/blob/master/lib/role_model/class_methods.rb

Turns out role_model creates methods dynamically based on assigned roles- so that's why it wasn't showing up in source...

From **class_methods.rb**:

```
# Defines dynamic queries for :role
#   #is_<:role>?
#   #<:role>?
#
# Defines new methods which call #is?(:role)
def define_dynamic_queries(roles)
  dynamic_module = Module.new do
    roles.each do |role|
      ["#{role}?".to_sym, "is_#{role}?".to_sym].each do |method|
        define_method(method) { is? role }
      end
    end
  end
  include dynamic_module
end
```