# Why do some rake tests fail with 'method_missing: private method location called for...'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm upgrading a Rails 4.0 app to Rails 4.2. All the tests passed prior to the upgrade. However, I am now getting several errors (but no failures). This is the output of one of the tests:

```
Run options: --seed 30437

# Running:

E

Finished in 1.738307s, 0.5753 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:171:in `method_missing': private method `location' called for #<[MyTestClass]:0xb46557c> (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:397:in `method_missing'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:265:in `block in to_s'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:264:in `map'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:264:in `to_s'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:580:in `%'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:580:in `block in aggregated_results'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:579:in `each'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:579:in `each_with_index'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:579:in `each'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:579:in `map'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:579:in `aggregated_results'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:566:in `report'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:638:in `each'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:638:in `report'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:134:in `run'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

I can't seem to find anything in my code that could be causing this error. Looking at some of the files mentioned in the stacktrace, it looks like it is erroring while trying to generate a failure message. (Double fail...)

What is the cause of this error?

**Edit:**

The first line of my test is `s = login(:user)`. If I place a `return` before that line, the test passes, but if I place it after that line, I still get the error. The `login` function is defined in my `test_helper.rb` as follows:

```
def login(user)
  open_session do |sess|
    u = users(user)
    sess.extend(MySession)
    sess.get "/users/sign_in"
    sess.assert_response :success
    sess.post_via_redirect "/users/sign_in",
      user: {
        email: u.email,
        password: "<password>"
      }
    assert_equal '/', sess.path
    assert_equal "Signed in successfully.", sess.flash[:notice]
  end
end
```

The module `MySession` contains a few helper methods.

**Edit 2:**

I opened a `rails console` session, `require`d my test class, and did `MyTestClass.private_methods`. This was the output:

```
=> [:initialize, :_stash_object_in_method, :_superclass_delegating_accessor, :included, :extended, :prepended, :method_added, :method_removed, :method_undefined, :initialize_copy, :attr, :attr_reader, :attr_writer, :attr_accessor, :initialize_clone, :remove_const, :using, :remove_method, :undef_method, :alias_method, :public, :protected, :private, :define_method, :attr_internal_ivar_name, :attr_internal_define, :DelegateClass, :Digest, :timeout, :default_src_encoding, :Nokogiri, :irb_binding, :create_fixtures, :load, :require, :initialize_dup, :sprintf, :format, :Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :Hash, :warn, :raise, :fail, :global_variables, :__method__, :__callee__, :__dir__, :eval, :local_variables, :iterator?, :block_given?, :catch, :throw, :loop, :respond_to_missing?, :trace_var, :untrace_var, :at_exit, :syscall, :open, :printf, :print, :putc, :puts, :gets, :readline, :select, :readlines, :p, :srand, :rand, :trap, :require_relative, :proc, :lambda, :binding, :caller, :caller_locations, :exec, :fork, :exit!, :system, :spawn, :sleep, :exit, :abort, :Rational, :Complex, :set_trace_func, :gem_original_require, :Pathname, :URI, :rubygems_require, :BigDecimal, :j, :jj, :JSON, :not_implemented, :y, :open_uri_original_open, :pp, :singleton_method_added, :singleton_method_removed, :singleton_method_undefined, :method_missing]
```

**Edit 3:**

I opened a `rails console` session, `require`d my test class, and did `test = MyTestClass.new` and then `test.private_methods`. This time, the output did contain `:location`. This app does have a `Location` model, and this output appeared in between several other of the app's models, so I suspect that is the problem. The question is now: why do my test classes have private methods named after my app's models? How can I fix or work around this problem? (Obviously I could rename the `Location` model, but I'd prefer to avoid that, if possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the `location` method change from public to private on whatever class you're calling it on between Rails 4.0 and 4.2?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the error seems pretty straightforward. Somewhere (in your code, or maybe a gem you rely on that's changed versions as well) a method called `location` is being called which is `private`. The stack track shows you where it's happening, so take a look at that code and see what's going on.

Might also be helpful to see the test code, but the stack trace is pointing you to the source from which you can trace back what's going on.

I looked through the code on github as well and can't find anything. Any chance you defined a method called `location` on `MyTestClass` that overrides the one in `MiniTest::Test` ? Also, if you go into your console and simply require the `MyTestClass`, and call `.private_methods` on it (or rather an instance of it), does `:location` indeed show up in the list? Any `include` statements anywhere that you can find in your code that might be bringing in a `location` method into `MyTestClass`?

It looks like this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime) might provide a way to track down where these methods are coming from.

Comment: That's the thing: I'm not calling a `location` method anywhere. I found some references to it in the `minitest` gem (mentioned in the stack trace), but the file that contains it (`.../minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest/test.rb`) does not contain the word `private` anywhere.

Comment: No to all three questions. See edit. The only `include` statement in my test class is `test_helper`.

Comment: Oops, actually I called `.private_methods` on the class, not the instance of it. I'll try that instead.

Comment: I've edited my post again. I think I've found the cause of the problem, now I just need to determine why.

Comment: If you edit the contents of your comment into your answer, I will likely accept it (especially if you know why this happens, and/or how I can work around it).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the link is missing though?

Comment: Thanks, got it figured out. I've suggested an edit with my results.

Comment: Your edit was rejected by the community. They feel it should be added as an answer (you can accept your own answer). Just thought I'd pass that feedback to you.

Comment: Done. I'll leave your answer as accepted, since you helped me find the source of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.method` and `.source_location` methods from @jefflunt's link, I was able to find the cause of the problem. When I did `test.method(:location).source_location` from the `rails console`, I got this output:

```
=> ["/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb", 885]
```

When I looked up that line in that file, I found a method that defines private accessor methods for each fixture. Since I had fixtures defined for my `Location` model, that was the cause of this problem.

Since I don't see another way around this problem (aside from perhaps ditching fixtures, which I'm not ready to put time into just yet), I'll be renaming my `Location` model.