# Call stack "around" ruby code

Tags: ruby, byebug

I have a line of Ruby-code with overloading methods. I want to show the call stack of the line.
I don't know the place for `caller` or `byebug`. I want to show the current call stack for the line after execution and find the place for debugging. How can I do it?

Approximately like `caller Test.method`, and after that:

```
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Hi, not sure of your code. You can try to raise an exception it will print out call stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly like that, but it's very similar.

You can use method `method`. For example

```
2.method(:hours)
=> #<Method: Fixnum(Numeric)#hours>
```

or probably more detail

```
2.method(:hours).source_location
=> ["~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb", 29]
```

and after that you can use debuger(if posible) or go deeper

Another detail in this answer [How to find where a method is defined at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime)