# ruby introspection: how to ask ruby where a method is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, introspection

I have a class like this in a rails app

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
end
```

The class doesn't have a method caller foo?
Nor does any of the `include ...` files.
But User.new.foo? does respond, so how can I ask where this method is defined?

Comment: oops I think it's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime

Comment: From the link you provided: `User.new.method(:foo?).owner`

Answer (score 2):

```
(byebug) User.last.method(:foo?)
#<Method: User(#<Module:0x007fd4c0a03da8>)#foo?>
(byebug) User.last.method(:foo?).source_location
["/Users/user1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/enum.rb", 122]
(byebug)
```